# Capistrano deployments to an nginx webserver results in bad asset URLs

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, deploy

I am using Capistrano to deploy Magento code to a webserver that is running nginx. Nginx web root for `test.url.com` is `/var/www/html`, which on the filesystem is a symlink to `/opt/magento-codebase/current` (which in itself is a symlink to `/opt/magento-codebase/releases/TIMESTAMP`). See http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/structure for more details on how Cap. sets up its directories.

Everything loads right, except for assets described in Magento's layout XML files. When generating the URLs via the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addItem()` method it ends up including the full path to the file in the URL. For example, `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/tools.css</name></action>` results in:

```
http://test.url.com/opt/magento-codebase/releases/TIMESTAMP/skin/frontend/store1/default/css/tools.css
```

should be

```
http://test.url.com/skin/frontend/store1/default/css/tools.css
```

Is there an nginx or Magento configuration I can use to tell it not to include the resolved directory? I'm testing this locally and we are not combining JS assets or CSS assets into the hashed file stored in `/media` yet.

Update: I checked and when `dev/js/merge_files` is set to `1` and `dev/css/merge_css_files` is set to `1` in `core_config_data`, it doesn't work. WhenI set them to `0`, it loads correctly...

Comment: So only when javascript *and* CSS are merged via admin your URLs are malformed? Start by looking at the logic that does the merging: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/cf43f51aab6125f03a0083df1c00ac0f34b86c86/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php#L653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be permissions in the shared `media` and `var` folders. Once I set the group for those folders to be `nginx` and add the `bamboo` user to the `nginx` group, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I encounter this problem (not as part of Capistrano deployments), I can quickly resolve by:

- Turning off CSS merge
- Flushing cache storage
- Or, flushing CSS/JS cache
- Turning on CSS merge

Sounds like you were onto this already, but to be sure were you flushing cache in between settings changes?

Answer (score 0):

Its a magento bug, you can open a support ticket and request the  PATCH_SUPEE-2662_EE_1.13.1.0_v1 patch.